# Understanding the Sobolev space $H^k([a,b];H^m(\mathbb{R}^d))$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I saw this space in the mathematical literature but I do not really understand what this means.

Is $H^k([a,b];H^m(\mathbb{R}^d))$ the same space as $H^{k,m}([a,b] \times \mathbb{R}^d)$?-Note that for $L^2$ spaces $L^2(A;L^2(B))= L^2(A \times B)$. So to work with this in a more explicit way, if I apply to some $u \in H^k([a,b];H^m(\mathbb{R}^d))$ the Laplacian to get $\Delta u$. Is this then an element of $H^k([a,b];H^{m-2}(\mathbb{R}^d))$?

Or another example question: Does the Schwartz-rule hold? So assume $k,m \ge 1$ is it then true that $\partial_t \partial_{x_2} u =\partial_t \partial_{x_2}u$ where $t \in [a,b]$ and $(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^d$? Cause this would be true in $H^{k,m}([a,b] \times \mathbb{R}^d).$

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: What is your definition for $H^{k,m}([a,b]\times\mathbb{R}^d)$? In your second paragraph what do you mean by $\Delta u$ (Laplacian on which domain)? In your third paragraph, did you actually mean $\partial_t\partial_{x_2} u = \partial_{x_2} \partial_t u$? As written the two sides are trivially the same.

Comment: @WillieWong $H^{k,m}([a,b] \times \mathbb{R}^d)$ means functions that are $k-$ times weakly differentiable w.r.t time and $m$ times w.r.t. spatial coordinates. $\Delta: H^m \subset H^{m-2} \rightarrow H^{m-2}.$ and yes, I mean it like that. Because what is not clear to me is in which way you can interpret elements in $H^k([a,b];H^{m-2})$ as functions taking elements of $[a,b] \times \mathbb{R}^d$ rather than $H^2$ maps $t \mapsto u(t) \in H^{m}.$

Comment: Which books/papers are you following? What is the definition of $H^k ([a,b], H^m(\mathbb R^d))$. I have a definition of $H^k ([a,b], X)$ in mind but I want to be sure.

Comment: @JohnMa yes exactly, it is the standard definition of Sobolev spaces in the context of Bochner integrals (so exactly as for Lebesgue integrals, but with Bochner integrals). By the way, I improved the question a bit on the other thread, so you might focus on that one :-)